# Using $_POST to get select option value from more than two dropdown lists HTML

Tags: php, html-select

How can I fill a MySql query using php's $_POST from more than two dropdown lists?

Lets say I have the following three dropdowns in a HTML form:

```
    <form method="post" action="myphpscript.php">
    <select name="country">
      <option value="1">Belgium</option>
      <option value="2">Canada</option>
      <option value="3">Spain</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year">
        <option value="2001">First</option>
        <option value="2002">Second</option>
        <option value="2003">Third</option>
      </select>
    <select name="virus">
        <option value="hiv">HIV</option>
        <option value="hcv">HCV</option>
        <option value="hbv">HBV</option>
      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
  </form>
```

Then I have my query:

```
<?php   
    $query=sprintf("select country, year, virus from f_report where      country='%s' and year ='%s' and virus ='%s'",
          mysqli_escape_string($con,$_POST["country"]),
          mysqli_escape_string($con,$_POST["year"]),
          mysqli_escape_string($con,$_POST["virus"]));?>
```

How can I get this query to work if, for example, the user selected only "country"?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I got it! I need to use sprint() so that my database is not vulnerable to attacks. Sorry.

Comment: Bit better now. Still, you should switch to PDO to save some efforts anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about this.

1. you can assign default values by verifying `$_POST['key']` is empty for example

   ```
   $_POST['year'] = isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : 'default value';
   ```

or

2. Set the optional fields to `null` in your database.

I hope it helps.